# Sudoku solver in Haskell

Tags: haskell, sudoku

I tried to implement a naive brute-force Sudoku solver in Haskell (I know there are [loads of good solutions already](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Sudoku)) and I'd like some reviews from you experts.

The solver is very simple and it uses the List monad to try all the possible combinations. It's not optimized at all, but it takes an awful lot of time to solve even the simplest grids.
I'm trying to understand if there is a problem with the algorithm itself (too simple) or with my implementation.

Anyway, here is the code.

```
    module Main where

    import Data.List (nub, concat, findIndices)
    import Control.Monad (liftM2, forM, join, guard)
    import Data.Maybe (catMaybes, fromMaybe)
    import Debug.Trace

    type Board = String

    --  Some boards
    --  other examples: http://norvig.com/top95.txt
    boards :: [Board]
    boards = map parseBoard [
            "4.....8.5.3..........7......2.....6.....8.4......1.......6.3.7.5..2.....1.4......",
            "..3.2.6..9..3.5..1..18.64....81.29..7.......8..67.82....26.95..8..2.3..9..5.1.3..",
            "483921657967345821251876493548132976729564138136798245372689514814253769695417382",
            "483...6..967345....51....93548132976..95641381367982453..689514814253769695417..2",
            "..3.2.6..9..3.5..1..18.64....81.29..7.......8..67.82....26.95..8..2.3..9..5.1.3..",
            ".2.4.6..76..2.753...5.8.1.2.5..4.8.9.6159...34.28.3..1216...49.......31.9.8...2.."
            ]

    --  The idea is to try all the possibilities by substituting '.' with all
    --  possible chars and verifying the constraint at every step. When there are
    --  no more dots to try, backtrack.
    --  This is done in the List monad.
    solve :: Board -> [Board]
    --  solve board | trace (showBoard board) False = undefined
    solve board = go dotIdxs
            where dotIdxs = findIndices (== '.') board
                  go :: [Int] -> [Board]
                  go [] = do
                          -- no dots to try: just check constraints
                          guard $ not $ isObviouslyWrong board
                          return board
                  --  go dotIdxs | trace (show dotIdxs) False = undefined
                  go dotIdxs = do
                          -- in the List monad: try all the possibilities
                          idx <- dotIdxs
                          val <- ['1'..'9']
                          let newBoard = set board idx val
                          -- guard against invalid boards
                          guard $ not $ isObviouslyWrong board
                          -- carry on with the good ones
                          solve newBoard

    --  Create a new board setting board[idx] = val
    set :: Board -> Int -> Char -> Board
    set board idx val = take idx board ++ [val] ++ drop (idx + 1) board

    safeHead :: [a] -> Maybe a
    safeHead [] = Nothing
    safeHead (x:_) = Just x

    --  Block of indices where to verify constraints
    blockIdxs :: [[Int]]
    blockIdxs = concat [
            [[r * 9 + c | c <- [0..8]] | r <- [0..8]]  -- rows
          , [[r * 9 + c | r <- [0..8]] | c <- [0..8]]  -- cols
          , [[r * 9 + c | r <- [rb..rb + 2], c <- [cb..cb + 2]] | rb <- [0,3..8], cb <- [0,3..8]]  -- blocks
            ]

    --  Check if constrains hold on grid
    --  This means that block defined in blockIdxs does not contain duplicates, a
    --  part from '.'
    isObviouslyWrong :: Board -> Bool
    isObviouslyWrong board = any (isWrong board) blockIdxs
            where isWrong board blockIdx = nub blockNoDots /= blockNoDots
                   where blockNoDots = filter (/= '.') block
                         block = map (board !!) blockIdx

    --  Filter out spurious chars
    parseBoard :: Board -> Board
    parseBoard = filter (`elem` "123456789.")

    --  Pretty output
    showBoard :: Board -> String
    showBoard board = unlines $ map (showRow board) [0..8]
            where showRow board irow = show $ take 9 $ drop (irow * 9) board

    test :: Maybe Board
    test = safeHead . solve $ boards !! 2

    main :: IO ()
    main = interact $ showBoard . fromMaybe "Solution not found" . safeHead . solve . parseBoard
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A large part of the inefficiency may stem from the decision to represent partially completed boards as full-blown 81-element lists, vs. a representation that's more easily mutated.  For example, if a board were represented as a short list of only the (position,value) pairs selected so far, the selection of one more value could very inexpensively add another pair to the head of the existing list. This instead of "replacing a dummy '.' element" which typically involves expensive copying.

This will change the details of how you validate a board, but not by much -- you are just replacing "dense array" positional indexing and dummy '.' entries with "sparse array" key matching and skipped entries.

This change is also somewhat independent of the algorithm you use to decide which positions or values to try first, though different representations can influence this choice as they make it easier or harder to check for different patterns of likely/unlikely choices.

Answer (score 1):

The `set` operation would be slightly faster using `splitAt` instead of `take` and `drop`. Other than that I don't see obvious problems (which doesn't mean much).

I guess other data structures could help a lot (e.g. I think some vector implementation would be much faster as board representation).

The biggest problem is the algorithm: You definitely want to fill the fields with the least possibilities first. So the best way would be to calculate all candidates for the open fields in the beginning, start backtracking from a field with just a few possibilities (often the choice will be unique) and update the candidates in the same row, column and square accordingly.