# Speeding up naive backtracking Sudoku Solver in Haskell

Tags: performance, beginner, haskell, sudoku, backtracking

After watching a recent [computerphile video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_UYXzGuqvM) on building a very simple sudoku solver I tried to implement the same in Haskell. From [this CR question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/9281/51266) I learned that it is probably a better idea to use Vectors instead of just lists to represent a *grid* of numbers that is gonna be mutated. (But it is supposedly still worse than using a sparse representation.) And from [this one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/164317/51266) (and [another question of mine](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/166865/puzzle-game-solver-via-backtracking)) I learned about `Control.Lens`, but I decided against using it to avoid using many different packages that I'm not familiar with.

Now the program I wrote is close to the original in python, but very slow. So I would like to get some feedback on how to speed it up without deviating form this very simple aproach too much.

#### The Program

The code defines a `Board` that represents a (solved or unsolved) state, with zeros for the entries that area yet to be determined. It can be indexed using `Coordinates`. Then there are a few setters and getters that probably could be replaced by using `Control.Lens` - but I'd like to avoid that for now as I just want to focus on the performance. Then there is a `possible` function which takes a `Board`, `Coordinates` and a candidate number an just reports whether it is possible to put the candidate at some given coordinates. Finally there is `solve` that does the backtracking.

So far I tried to add a `take 1 $` or `take 1 $!` to speed it up (but only returning at most a single solution), but without success.

```hs
--https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_UYXzGuqvM
import qualified Data.Vector as V

data Board = Board (V.Vector (V.Vector Integer))
type Coordinates = (Int, Int)

instance Show Board where
 show (Board b)=unlines . V.toList $ V.map show b

fromList :: [[Integer]] -> Board
fromList l = Board $ V.fromList $ V.fromList <$> l

-- a few setters and getters
(!):: Board -> Coordinates -> Integer
(Board b) ! (i,j) = (b  V.! j)V.! i

getColumn :: Board -> Coordinates -> [Integer]
getColumn b (i, _) = [b ! (i, j) | j<-[0..8]]

getRow :: Board -> (Int, Int) -> [Integer]
getRow b (_, j) = [b ! (i, j) | i<-[0..8]]

getSquare :: Board -> Coordinates -> [Integer]
getSquare b (i, j) = [b ! (i'*3 + u, j'*3 + v) | u<-[0..2],v<-[0..2]]
 where i' = i `div` 3
       j' = j `div` 3

insert :: Board -> Coordinates -> Integer -> Board
insert (Board b) (i, j) k = Board b'
 where v = b V.! j
       v' = v V.// [(i, k)]
       b' = b V.// [(j, v')]


-- check whether it is possible to insert candidate at given position
possible :: Board -> Coordinates -> Integer -> Bool
possible b coords@(i, j) k
 |i < 0 || i >= 9 || j < 0 || j >= 9 || k < 0 || k > 9 = undefined
 |b ! coords > 0 = False
 |k `elem` getRow b coords = False
 |k `elem` getColumn b coords = False
 |k `elem` getSquare b coords = False
 |otherwise = True

-- check whether board is already full
full :: Board -> Bool
full b = 0 `notElem` [b ! (i,j) | i<-[0..8], j<-[0..8]]

-- recursion to find all solutions to a given board
solve :: Board -> [Board]
solve b
 |full b = [b]
 |otherwise =  concat[ solve $! (insert b (x, y) n)|
                       x<-[0..8],
                       y<-[0..8],
                       n<-[1..9],
                       possible b (x,y) n]

main = print $ solve b

-- normal sudoku
b :: Board
b = fromList [
 [5,3,0,0,7,0,0,0,0],
 [6,0,0,1,9,5,0,0,0],
 [0,9,8,0,0,0,0,6,0],
 [8,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,3],
 [4,0,0,8,0,3,0,0,1],
 [7,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,6],
 [0,6,0,0,0,0,2,8,0],
 [0,0,0,4,1,9,0,0,5],
 [0,0,0,0,8,0,0,7,9]
 ]

-- only one a few entries are missing
c :: Board
c = fromList [
 [0,0,0,0,9,4,5,6,1],
 [9,2,1,5,3,6,8,7,4],
 [4,5,6,7,8,1,9,2,3],
 [1,4,7,3,5,9,2,8,6],
 [2,8,3,6,1,7,4,5,9],
 [5,6,9,8,4,2,3,1,7],
 [6,7,4,9,2,5,1,3,8],
 [8,9,2,1,7,3,6,4,5],
 [3,1,5,4,6,8,7,9,2]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVVrb@JGFP0@v@JGihS8Na8AAaKQVt12V5XaL91utJVlhbE9hAEzw9pjs1T89/Te8dhA9hlHznDm3DPnPoYseb4Wafr83G4vjdnmt93ubrfr7HVhikh0Yr3p7riJlz@Xs7eP7//98N/b4mP5F5Obrc4MfCx4KhdSJPAbN7zzIGKjM@A5PDCWIAK/ap4lMHN/Ww815bj6QxnxJDLPY2a/FfBa6yyRihuRY1gLd32ieIxJlRuuYgHvlnrnBHdLkQkGOSGtCoq8WaFSqTC@Aw8do/@UuYFLXG74tmJGjC0yvbEbt7cQBM5DGEL7vlI@EtLGPWk08NmHu8t7SBlrt4HDQuwgF8aILAeuEniq1qx14eFZlRKecponfnQOWJMEXEBL@iuPihABHnYBK4/ekjGUfK3TYqPgG4pNUif0iDThkUSDqDoBVeEAq7t20Ot0JmFo1f/GIp1KH9vwmTJRUfbRCr2Uleey73BcMvHDph09qvUa9atXA/gJCgSrVUlnFdVZ16Ff1quQVQMC8gqDJcwTWc5hwKD6WRG6alAaMJEZ@H6XjlPiQo5dc1bXzdBEV7WJErGoamTtoCQHJWLdLgQUuvbCei@6cny7t/KRfNy0sxYvRbwmcYP6IA3IHLY6z2WUCjAanLkYp1DiZRTADTzJUihiSSO1Yg39R5PW6TEmgpiY@S910gwOEu6gBwdsPdzPYEqrVQ2tGmhdQ2u4R2QGhUrEAu9sghLU40oYN3u4@YanOV7ywxrmIhWbOTRj52hfpjQz/01WM2SfsTSVdSdzgdg/WSG@UPPIlgzLztNM8GQPiyJNGb3OCmrLZtEItXowV9r8bg3U1@X8tvhn9xFPzURcZDk2jNqKdUrwwBRyTJC6mBPKXWutJYZb5XlTA7sK3U6E@TWGgih8kS4WQ8XcBFCxL8ljNUx4GT/5sPdAeYd6GF/@fGry@Bpj/12GQka/05l@nXEyhmiJHGGtNlwq9L/NpKKv6DpZqqHS2YZj0YpErwsWNcVhVILmmzxgEIz8gd/DZ2zf@JCJ4Mau@/7UH52gPfw8qXn@jUMnx8/2GVh0aNe0V@n3LVqfcl3HON2bRvWaYhxKz9C6oNXoBO05H2N/iu3EX0paq3SPL@H@LwllMom3miZ@I7F@6onFx0rELytRK0/xzBE6qhxP0VHfpyrd4Jljf@iyI8YYEXJ37XLuY@QYmSOLTVx2tKLoPkXTnkUpnqo5pGjac3UnDkWPEBv4E1fhysXY6gxdJQbW19D5Qgben@fn/wE)

Comment: Since I don't have a Haskell environment at hand, just a short question instead of a full-answer: did you profile your program?

Comment: @Zeta No I haven't, thanks for the suggestion. Can you recommend a place to start out with profiling? I have never profiled Haskell programs.

Comment: That's from the top of my head, but try `-prof -fprof-auto -O<optimization-level>` via GHC. If you use `stack`, there should be `--profile` for `stack`'s build command. Afterwards, you have to tell the runtime to write a profile. On your application, use `+RTS -p`. That's the quick gist. I believe some of my old answers here on CR contain examples on profiling.

Comment: Keep in mind that you need to compile all your dependencies (e.g. `vector` and probably `primitive`) also with profiling enabled, which can take a while.

Comment: @Zeta Thanks, I'm trying this right now - I do have some errors to figure out but I'll report back as soon as I get it running:)

Comment: *"Now the program I wrote is close to the original in python, but very slow. "* I'm currently running your program on a Windows 10 machine with profiling enabled, and thus far it took more than 7 minutes without any result. How slow is "very slow" on your site?

Comment: It never let it terminate. I now realized I made a mistake: Even in the event of success no sudoku is returned - I now fixed that and added a trivial test case `c` just as a sanity check.

Comment: @Zeta Thanks for your advice, it turns out I misunderstood something in the way the python program worked that I should have caught when testing. With a small modification it runs fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I made some crucial mistakes: The iteration in `solve` can stop as soon we have tried all possibilities for *one* coordinate `(x,y)` that is not set yet. If we iterate further over `(x,y)` we get duplicate solutions which makes things blow up, so with following little modification we get results immediately:

```
isEmpty :: Board -> Coordinates -> Bool
isEmpty b coords = b ! coords == 0

-- check whether board is already full
full :: Board -> Bool
full b = 0 `notElem` [b ! (i,j) | i<-[0..8], j<-[0..8]]

-- recursion to find all solutions to a given board
solve :: Board -> [Board]
solve b
 |full b = [b]
 |otherwise =  concat[ solve $! (insert b (x, y) n)|
                       (x,y) <- take 1 empty,
                       n <- [1..9],
                       possible b (x,y) n]
   where empty = [(x,y) | x<-[0..8],y<-[0..8], isEmpty b (x, y)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVVra9swFP2uX3ELhcabk6XPtaMpYy8Y7NM6@sWYRY6VVrEjZZacLpD/nt0r2XLSdtlicOWjo3MfOpc@cFOIstxs5HyhKwu/al7KqRQ5fOKWD@7ExOoKuIE7xnJE4IPmVQ6j5m/vrqV0q6/KintRRRGzq4WAj1pXuVTcCoPHergbEyViTCpjuZoIuH3Qj43g44OoBANDSM9DWTSqVSkVnh/A3cDqb9JYOMTlnC88M2NsWum523j3DpKkySFNoX/jlTtCGbInjQDvfFwf3kDJWL8PHKbiEYywVlQGuMrh3q9Z7yDCWF4Jo2zXiZ9NBiwUAQfQk/EsoiZkgMEOYBbRWzKGkh91Wc8V7FEMRW3RM9KEnySaZD4CqsIaZtf9ZDgYXKapU/@OTdqW7q7hmTJRUfanE3oqK3dlb9EulfjvpBt61uoF9aNXp/AaagT9akmxah/rJI2X7Spl3iAgj/CwhHEul2M4ZeB/M0JnASWDicrCv2@pc0lzpLu1JtUimCY7apNYIpb5i2wzWFIGS8TevIGEjhZR2u5lRw3f7c1iJHebzmuTBzEpSNyiPkgL0sBCGyOzUoDV0CQ3QRdKHEYB3MK9XApFLGmlVizQ/7doXXZnMpgQ07xvi2awlnANQ1jj1cPNCK5oNWuhWYCKFirgBpER1CoXU5zZHCWUpumS5vN8YVchCJK@8NLgsK8LGItSzMcQ7LeXEry/lxXM9oylqb2P0gjEflS1QKM0ue1pmuvUCzWQgduPEQxfuMfMKeJV8rISPF/BtC5LRq@deC6AQzOUHcIY2/bZFdOO4O4ExjszjlErMakrgyYgq2DvcwxYgsFmkTMMobyxi0uJ4dZy1yiJW6XNToa9CgklWfqkdVi2mnCbgGcfUo7eoDjgv2NYRaCidWvwpz9kIOG6D5YXAo5BUGPjv7EVMZPjweAq/Stny8ZeXLnp8rPq5KkMv7WG36GPq66j3f36ArCxcy4VnltUUpGL285Qw5Wu5hw7XOe6qFkWOsmoX@FfScIgOY9P4yE@b90bH6oiuXDr4/gqPt9Ch/h92fLiiwa97L7dc@rQM7emPa9/7NA2ykl7ptG9CKondKZB6TlzWdDqfAsdhjyusJPpZvMH)